# How to construct a specific regular expression

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I want to create a regular expression that replaces every character in a string except the last 2 with a '*'. For example:
'abcdefgh' --> '******gh'

I am using oracle's regexp_replace, I have written something like:

```
regexp_replace('dfdfdfdfsdf','(.*)(..)','*\2',1,0)
```

but it ends up with one "*"

```
dfdfdfdfsdf --> *df
```

I would appreciate your kind assistance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So long as you are not worried about 1 or 2 character strings then you can use the regular expression `.(..$)?`:

**Query**

```sql
WITH test_data ( value ) AS (
  SELECT NULL     FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'A'      FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'AB'     FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'ABC'    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'ABCD'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'ABCDE'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'ABCDEF' FROM DUAL
)
SELECT value,
       REGEXP_REPLACE(
         value,
         '.(..$)?',
         '*\1'
       )
FROM   test_data
```

**Outputs**:

> ```
> VALUE  | REGEXP_REPLACE(VALUE,'.(..$)?','*\1')
> :----- | :------------------------------------
> null   | null                                 
> A      | *                                    
> AB     | **                                   
> ABC    | *BC                                  
> ABCD   | **CD                                 
> ABCDE  | ***DE                                
> ABCDEF | ****EF
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=633a0c52028657b01d17ce1d348f67f9)*

Answer (score 4):

You can use `LPAD`.

```
select LPAD(SUBSTR('dfdfdfdfsdf',-2),LENGTH('dfdfdfdfsdf'),'*') from dual;
```

OUTPUT

```
*********df
```

[**CHECK LIVE DEMO HERE**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=8b3556df4a5456c28066c90de6587ea6)

Comment: Thank you but it has to be a regular expression because I am turning it to a redaction policy.

Answer (score 0):

You can try replacing this pattern by *:

```
.(?=.{2})
```

Live example:  https://regex101.com/r/uueD6B/1

Comment: This does not work in Oracle as look-ahead/behind is not supported.

Comment: That's right it didn't work with Oracle regexp_replace. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that. Should have tested it first. Anyway, neat solution MT0.